# Implement a specific dropdown-menu design

Tags: html, css

I want to implement a dropdown menu. I am not very familiar with CSS, but I could come up with the following code which implements the functionality I want but not the design :

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .dropbtn {
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      color: gray;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #f2f7f3;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">My dropdown menu</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">linkA</a>
      <a href="#">linkB</a>
      <a href="#">linkC</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

The design I wish to implemented is similar to [this one](https://dribbble.com/shots/5656738-UI-Dropdown). There are no borders and no background in the "title" of the dropdown menu (the text that we hover the mouse upon to show the menu). Only the arrow at the right of the title indicated that there is a dropdown menu.

I don't know where to start to have something visually similar.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking... But I would start with trying to find actual examples of dropdown menus to get an idea of how they are designed. E.g. [Bootstrap dropdowns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#single-button) use the [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) selector to add an arrow to indicate it's a dropdown.

Comment: What does having borders/backgrounds or not, have to do with _anything_? If you don’t want borders or backgrounds - well then don’t _specify_ any for the elements in question. What you _will_ have to pay attention to here though, is the “empty” spaces between the elements. You must not achieve those by using margins or positioning away from the parent element, otherwise you will be creating “holes” where the cursor isn’t over any of the elements, and then anything hover-based will fail. Those any of that spacing must be realized by padding _inside_ of elements.

Comment: @dada : Please accept my answer if its solving your problem so other User can have help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the background color of `.dropbtn` on hover. Also, to make it generic, use same class for sub menus so you can use the same css.
To show the right arrow `>` on parent item for submenu, use `::after` css.

See the Code Snippet below and look for the comments:

```css
.dropbtn {
      background-color: #fff;
      color: gray;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 8px;
      font-family: "Calibri";
      min-width: 165px;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .dropbtn:hover{
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      font-family: "Calibri";
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      z-index: 1;
      border-radius: 8px; 
      border-right: 3px white solid;
      border-top: 3px white solid;
    }
    /* Show '>' sign if there is any submenu */
    .dropdown:not(:first-child) > .dropbtn:first-child::after{
      content: " >";
      position: absolute;
      right:30px;
    }
    /* Show submenu after the menu on right */
    .dropdown > .dropdown-content{
      left:170px;
      top:0;
    }
    
    /* Reset for main menu */
    .dropdown:first-child > .dropdown-content{
      left:0;
      top:50px;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content button {
      color: gray;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content button:hover {color: #000}
    
    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #f2f7f3;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">My dropdown menu</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
      <button class="dropbtn">linkA</button>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">linkB</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <button class="dropbtn">linkB 1</button>
            <button class="dropbtn">linkB 2</button>
            <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">linkB 3</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
            <button class="dropbtn">linkB 3.1</button>
            <button class="dropbtn">linkB 3.2</button>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <button class="dropbtn" href="#">linkC</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

You can also check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/hng834u2/) on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the background/border you need to -

```
 .dropbtn {
      background:none;
}
```

and if you don't want any background when you hover, you need to remove this -

```
  .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
          background-color: #f2f7f3;
        }
```